# Creating Event Onset Variable

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have clinical data that records a patient at three time points with a disease outcome indicated by a binary variable. It looks something like this

```
patientid <- c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102)
time <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
outcome <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0) 

Data<- data.frame(patientid=patientid,time=time,outcome=outcome)
Data
```

I want to create an onset variable, so for each patient it would code a 1 for the time which the patient first got the disease, but would then be a 0 for any time period before or a time period after (even if that patient still had the disease). For the example data it should now look like this.

```
patientid <- c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102)
time <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
outcome <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0) 
outcome_onset <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)

Data<- data.frame(patientid=patientid,time=time,outcome=outcome, 
outcome_onset=outcome_onset)
Data
```

Therefore I would like some code/ some help automating the creation of the outcome_onset variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `cumsum` to create a logical vector after grouping by the 'patientid'

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
   group_by(patientid) %>%
   mutate(outcome_onset = +(cumsum(outcome) == 1))
```

---

Or use `match` and `%in%`

```
Data %>%
   group_by(patientid) %>% 
   mutate(outcome_onset = +(row_number() %in% match(1, outcome_onset)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `which.max` to get the index of 1st one in `outcome` variable and make that row as 1 and rest of them as 0.

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(patientid) %>%
  mutate(outcome_onset = as.integer(row_number() %in% which.max(outcome)), 
         outcome_onset = replace(outcome_onset, is.na(outcome), NA))

#  patientid  time outcome outcome_onset
#      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>         <int>
#1       100     1       0             0
#2       100     2       1             1
#3       100     3       1             0
#4       101     1       0             0
#5       101     2       0             0
#6       101     3       1             1
#7       102     1       1             1
#8       102     2       1             0
#9       102     3       0             0
```

Comment: Is there a way to account for missing data in the outcome column... I keep getting the following warning "number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)"

Comment: @BenjaminKrick Are you sure you are copying the code correctly and in a fresh R session. This answer should not have any impact of `NA` values.

Comment: you are correct, your code does work. Trying to keep the n/a. For example if there is an n/a in the outcome then it stays n/a in outcome onset

Comment: See updated answer which will make `NA` in `outcome_onset` if `outcome` has `NA`.

Comment: is there a way to adapt this code so that the index of 1st one in outcome variable and make that row as 1 and rest of them as NA